# Finding all members with a role in Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried literally using what everyone says and it just keeps giving me empty arrays or undefined. I am using discord.js v12 I believe.
I am REALLY certain that I actually have members with this role and that the roleID is correct. Why is this wrong? compare new_channel to channel. I suppose the `${}` in the find function is not necessary but that is not the issue. Up to the roles.cache.get(importantRole.id) part it goes right, but I can't seem to get the members from it.

```
let importantRole = await new_channel.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === `${new_channel.name}`)
console.log(importantRole.id) // --> gives the right role ID
let membersWithRole = await new_channel.guild.roles.cache.get(importantRole.id).members.map(m=>m.user.id);
console.log(membersWithRole) // --> gives []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the members with that role are not cached. You need to:

1. Enable the `GUILD_MEMBERS` privileged intent on the Discord developer panel if you have not already (if your bot is less than 100 guilds this is a simple toggle; if your bot has >100 guilds and is verified you need to apply for these, it's to protect user privacy), and
2. Enable the `GUILD_MEMBERS` privileged intent in your Discord.js Client's options (the object that is passed to `new Client({...})` by passing `{ ws: { intents: [ 'GUILD_MEMBERS' ] } }`
3. Fetch all of the guild's members when this command/module/etc runs (only do this when strictly necessary, and not on an interval, as it causes an extra API call)

Also, there's no need to do `` `${variable}` `` as `variable` does the same thing. The `` ` `` and `${...}` syntax are only needed when merging variables with strings `` `like${this}` `` (= `'like' + this`)

To fetch all guild members, you can do:

```js
<Guild>.members.fetch() // => Promise<GuildMemberManager>
```

Note that for some reason, in my testing, the value of the resolved promise doesn't work as a valid `GuildMemberManager`, so you should do:

```js
//                            _ = temporary var
<Guild>.members.fetch().then((_) => {
    // do something with <Guild>.members.cache
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know there was an option for GUILD_MEMBERS in the bot settings, much less that it was necessary to use in this case. That seemed to have done the trick. Weird that this is the first time in my code that I bumped into this problem.

Comment: @mikemaster98 They recently added these intents to the API. For **anything** involving guild members being in cache, you need the intent.